# How tests for Jpa criteria api should looks like?

Tags: java, testing

I'm learning tests and I consider situation when i have class like that:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SearchCustomerService {
    private final CustomerRepository CustomerRepository;

    public Page<CustomerDTO> search(CustomerCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
        CustomerSpecification specification = new CustomerSpecification(criteria);
        return customerRepository.findCustomers(specification, pageable);
    }
}
```

How tests should looks like? I think unit tests are not that really good because what am I actually testing? I'm just getting some data from database and if I mock repository.. then I test Mockito, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create integration test that includes persistence layer (eg inmemory H2), service and meaningfull dependencies, where your input would be a proper set of `Customer` entities in the repository, and assert outcome of invoking `search` based on some criterias.

To make it a unit test, I can you could only assert the shape of `CustomerSpecification`  but that will not guarantee that specs itself are valid for given case - thus makes small sense.

This case is similar to testing native queries execution. You don't assert SQL string, but assert result having test data set.